# Replacing Backup Exec 2010 R3 - Need Recommendations

Tags: backup, exec

I have been upgrading servers over the last few weeks, and stumbled on the realization that our current backup solution needs to change due to incoming incompatibilities. We currently use Symantec Backup Exec 2010 R3 to do weekly backups of eight VMs; full, incremental, and removable duplicates of the full backups. We need something to replace it, ideally not subscription based, which will perform the same function reliably, and also ideally be easy(ish) to configure. And it needs to support WS2008 R2 through WS2016.

Also, we do not need a solution for cloud backups. We currently do not have one, but at one of our other sites we use exclusively cloud backups and so we're good there.

Thanks!!! serverfault rocks!!!

Comment: Upgrade to Backup Exec 16?

Comment: Backup Exec 16's licensing is subscription based.

Comment: The Capacity Editions are subscription based. You can certainly continue using a la carte licensing with Backup Exec 16 if you choose to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your budget is, but at a previous job I used EMC Networker combined with a Data Domain.  Was able to backup windows vms (on vcenter) using the data domain plugin (can't remember name), complete backups every 6 hours for a lot more than 8 vms (probably close to 100), and got nearly 99% deduplication, because of how similar all the vms were.  This allowed us to store 1.2 pb on less than 15tb of storage.  Since they were all completes, they could be restored pretty quickly, and the windows backups allow individual file restores, even through the vm.  In fact, with the data domain you could spawn a vm right off the backup, if you needed to, for nearly instant restore.

It may be out of your budget though, I think the license for networker was pretty expensive.